# Gocd pipeline linking to .git repository to generate artifact

Tags: git, maven, go-cd

I have a git repository and it contains maven project under it.For example

- -repo-sample
      --sampleproject
          --src
          --pom.xml

so repo-sample as git repository and sampleproject under it which is a maven project.

Now in gocd pipeline,i want to trigger this project for every change and generate artifact.But unfortunately, i don't understand how will i give the path of my project.

It is easy for me to trigger it structure is like below.

- repo-sample
       -src
       -pom.xml

I can give below command in go cd stages to trigger pipeline.
 - mvn clean deploy -Dbuild.number=${GO_PIPELINE_LABEL} --batch-mode
and Material will refer to - git@bitbucket.org:com/rep-sample.git
Above setup is working fine for me.
Now to refer it like this git@bitbucket.org:com/rep-sample.git/sampleproject 
How will i give the setup.

Answer (score 0):

After you create your material it should look similar to this:

[image: GoCD Git Material]

Because we haven't specified a `Destination Directory`, the material will be cloned to the current directory `./` and not inside `repo-sample`.

Inside your task where you'll be executing the `mvn` command, it should look something like this:

[image: GoCD Maven Deploy Task]

Taking note of the `Working Directory`. This will essentially cause GoCD to cd to the `sampleproject` folder. That's where the `mvn clean package` command will be executed from.